# Django migrations no changes detected after changing directory structure

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have created a Django project using this directory structure :

```
bi3online
    __init__.py
    migrations
        __init__.py
    static
    templates
    media
    manage.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
    ...
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it only creates migrations for `auth` app and then when I try again it says no changes detected. It seems that migrations work only with apps but I'm not sure.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=64)
```

Comment: It detects models, that is `Model` subclasses in any `models` module/package within any of your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Did you use `python manage.py startproject arg` and `startapp arg`?

Comment: @iDrwish I created the project with `startproject bi3online` but I did not create any apps.

Comment: How come you have `models.py`, this only gets created with `startapp`? I am not sure that `migrate` will work without it. Do you have a reason to avoid `startapp`?

Comment: You need to use apps. Models generally will not work if they are not in an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sum up the comments and lead you to the solution:

Django works with apps. The app is a folder with `models.py`, `apps.py` and `views.py` modules (optionally other).

Say your app is called `books`. For Django to recognize the folder as an app you need to add your app to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... ,
    'books'
]
```

And you need your `apps.py` module in `books` folder to have this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BooksConfig(AppConfig):
     name = 'books'
```

And you should have the following project structure:

```
bi3online
    books
        migrations
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    bi3online
        __init__.py
        manage.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    static
    templates
    media
```